# Error while unmarshalling Web Service response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm calling a web service using JAX-WS.  I want to convert the content into a Java Object.

Here is the content portion of the web service response.

```
<header xmlns="">
  <store>
    <store_id>1</store_id>
    <store_name>ACME</store_name>
  </store>
</header>
```

I then created a class as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "store_id",
        "store_name" }) 
@XmlRootElement(name = "store") 
static public class store { 
   @XmlElement(name = "store_id", required = true)
   protected String store_id;

   @XmlElement(name = "store_name", required = true)
   protected String store_name;
}
```

My JAXB code:

```
List result = service.getService1Soap12().getDivisions().getContent();
ElementNSImpl e =(ElementNSImpl)result.get(0);
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(store.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement) um.unmarshal(e);
store customer = (store) element.getValue();
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"store"). Expected elements are <{http://tempuri.org/}header>
```

I've tried countless things to fix this.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the DOM element in an instance of `DOMSource` and doing the following:

```
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(e);
JAXBElement<store> element =
    unmarshaller.unmarshal(domSource, store.class);
```

By supplying the class you wish to unmarshal to, the JAXB impl does not need to determine the unmarshal class based on the root element.

Comment: This certainly helped...but now I'm getting nothing but null values in my object.  Thanks for getting me one step closer though!

Comment: @gshauger - If you populate your object model and marshal it out what does the resulting XML look like?

Comment: I know I posted this question a loooong time ago but I ended up using your feedback again for another project and wanted to say thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your root element is `<header ...>` not `<store>` as your StackTrace says.

Try to create new class Header with `@XmlRootElement(name="header")` annotation and `Store` class (not "store" with small "s") as it's attribute with `@XmlElement(name="store")` annotation (<- not sure if the XmlElement annotation is really needed if you have `@XmlRootElement` defined in Store class).